# Reactive Spring 5 Security with custom user service non-blocking

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following Spring 5 Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration(private val us: UserService) : UserDetailsRepository {

    override fun findByUsername(username: String?): Mono<UserDetails> {
        if (username != null) {
            val user = us.byUsername(username).block()
            val grantedAuthorities = user.roles!!
                    .map{SimpleGrantedAuthority(it)}

            var userDetails: UserDetails = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.username,
                    user.password, user.enabled, user.accountNonExpired, user.credentialsNonExpired,user.accountNonLocked,
                    grantedAuthorities)

            return userDetails.toMono()
        }
        throw UsernameNotFoundException("Username is null")
    }
}
```

I'm using a custom user service, and map this `User` to the Spring Security `UserDetails` object.  To get the `User` object, I need to use the `block()` statement.  Is there a way to make this code non-blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a java implementation

```
@Override
public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username).map(new Function<User, UserDetails>() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails apply(User user) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                    true, true, true, true, authorities);
        }
    });
}
```